# Modifying key in config file c#

Tags: c#, file, config

I have a program that reads app.config and will update the config file programatically.

For example:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key = "card" value = "rare" />
    <add key = "game" value = "poker" />
</appSettings>
```

After updating the config file, it should become like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key = "drink" value = "rare" />
    <add key = "game" value = "poker" />
</appSettings>
```

i know that i can remove the old key and value and add in the new ones.
But it always add to the last index.

I need it to be at the exact same index where i made the changes.

Sorry for the bad analogy and bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //UpdateSetting("language", "English");
            UpdateAppSettings("card", "drink", "water");
        }

        public static void UpdateAppSettings(string OldKeyName, string KeyName, string KeyValue)
        {
            XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            XmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

            foreach (XmlElement xElement in XmlDoc.DocumentElement)
            {
                if (xElement.Name == "appSettings")
                {

                    foreach (XmlNode xNode in xElement.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        if (xNode.Attributes[0].Value == OldKeyName)
                        {
                            xNode.Attributes[0].Value = KeyName;
                            xNode.Attributes[1].Value = KeyValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            XmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
        }
}
```

> > Remember not to test it from VS debugger. You should build in release mode and open that execute that binary from that folder to check the changes made to that app.config appsettings file.

Comment: @Kai Updated answer try that It work for me with exact same requirement as you wanted... :)